# how do we prove uniform continuity for some function

Tags: uniform-continuity

How do we prove if the following function

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ $;x>0$

is uniformly continous in $x>\frac{1}{2}$
 and not uniformly continous everywhere

and

$f(x)=x^{n}$ is uniformly continous in [$\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}$] and not in [0,1].

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f%28x%29%3D1%2Fx)

Comment: Well, it has bounded derivative in any interval $[\epsilon, 1]$ for $\epsilon > 0$. And it doesn't in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: If $n>0$ then $x^n$ is uniformly continuous on *any* closed and bounded interval (and so is any continuous function).

Comment: can you give more explaination for the above 2 questions?